# Star Wars non sci-fi description

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

I'm looking for a piece of writing that has been shared many times in social networks. It's a description of a story about a brother and sister who are separated at birth and their father has betrayed them etc. Etc. Etc.

It reads like the description of a Shakespearean play but at the end it reveals it to be Star Wars.

This particular one (like I said) has been shared all over social networks and I've read it several times before but now struggling to find it. It was really well written too.

Was wondering if anyone knows which one I'm talking about and where to find it.

Comment: Was it a fan fiction?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 not really a fan fiction. More like a plot summary where at the end they "reveal" that they are summarising Star Wars. It's a kind of argument against the "all sci-if films are geeky" or "all sci-fi films are the same/boring/for boys" etc...

Comment: Also, this particular thing I'm thinking of was only a couple of paragraphs long.

Comment: I've seen it, too, but it's one of those things that's impossible to search for because people only ever share the image, which is of text, and not the text itself. Only seen it on FB, that I recall.

Comment: @CreationEdge yes, that's the one I'm thinking of but like you said, really hard to search for :( thanks :D

Comment: There are a whole series of these inspired this synopsis for *The Wizard of Oz*: “Transported to a surreal landscape, a young girl kills the first woman she meets, then teams up with three complete strangers to kill again.” They're usually listed as "accurate but misleading descriptions" but, while I can find quite a few for individual *Star Wars* films, I can't find the one you describe, which I believe encompasses the entire original trilogy.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're thinking of [William Shakespeare's Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/William_Shakespeare%27s_Star_Wars)?

> Return once more to a a galaxy far, far away with this sublime retelling of George Lucas's epic Star Wars in the style of the immortal Bard of Avon. The saga of a wise (Jedi) knight and an evil (Sith) lord, of a beautiful princess held captive and a young hero coming of age, Star Wars abounds with all the valor and villainy of Shakespeare's greatest plays. 'Tis a tale told by fretful Droids, full of faithful Wookiees and fearsome Stormtroopers, signifying pretty much everything.
>
> Reimagined in glorious iambic pentameter, William Shakespeare's Star Wars will astound and edify Rebels and Imperials alike. Zounds! This is the book you're looking for.

Written by Ian Doescher and released in July 2013.

Comment: Nah, the piece in question is a short summary, a few paragraphs at most, which merely makes the story of Star Wars sound like a classical dramatic plot.